# Altair - Multiple lines chart using slider widget

Tags: python, slider, altair

Starting with [this dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Nf4.png) I want to create an interactive chart, where 'x' column is an x-axis and the rest of the columns ('1'-'10') are functions plotted on y-axis.

My idea is to use slider widget to select multiple functions (so in default only one function is plotted, by using the slider you can plot more lines up to all 10 functions at once - so slider works not like simple selector, instead the selection is let say 'cumulative').

I'm completely new to Altair. So far I've managed to plot all the functions at once, but slider selector doesn't work at all.

```
data = df.melt('x')
chart = alt.Chart(data).mark_line().encode(
    x='x',
    y='value',
    color='variable'
)

slider = alt.binding_range(min=1, max=10, step=1)
slider_selection = alt.selection_single(bind=slider, fields=['variable'])

chart.add_selection(slider_selection).transform_filter(slider_selection)
```

Please help.

PS. Data are generated as follows:

```
n = 50
Xtest = np.linspace(-5, 5, n).reshape(-1,1)

def kernel(a, b, param):
    sqdist = np.sum(a**2,1).reshape(-1,1) + np.sum(b**2,1) - 2*np.dot(a, b.T)
    return np.exp(-.5 * (1/param) * sqdist)

param = 0.1
K_ss = kernel(Xtest, Xtest, param)
L = np.linalg.cholesky(K_ss + 1e-15*np.eye(n))
f_prior = np.dot(L, np.random.normal(size=(n,10)))

df = pd.DataFrame(f_prior)
df.columns += 1
df['x'] = Xtest
df.columns = df.columns.map(str)
```

Comment: Please, add next time the actual data and not a picture) for faster turnaround. I used random numbers in my answer

Answer (score 0):

your code works just fine.
Only change you need to make - > check if the column 'variable' is actually an int...

data['variable']=data['variable'].astype(int)[image]

Comment: Now I can display one line at the time - it's better but still doesn't work as it suppose to :) My goal is to diplay from 1 up to 10 lines at the same time.

Comment: As @joelostblom answered here- This is currently not possible via a widget like a dropdown because it is not implemented in the underlying Vega and Vega-Lite libraries.  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73320968/2186559 but it is very easy to implement in streamlit.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [selection values in expressions](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/interactions.html#selection-values-in-expressions):

```
data = df.melt('x')
data['variable'] = data['variable'].astype(int)

chart = alt.Chart(data).mark_line().encode(
    x='x',
    y='value',
    color='variable:N'
)

slider = alt.binding_range(min=1, max=10, step=1, name='Function ')
slider_selection = alt.selection_single(bind=slider, fields=['variable'], name='function_selections', init=1)

chart.add_selection(slider_selection).transform_filter('function_selections.variable >= datum.variable')
```

[image]